# Credit Card Payments with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to create an app just like Fancy's App: https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/fancy/id407324335?mt=8

And I was wondering if there is a way to make payments like people can do on Fancy's App. Cause customers can make payments with debit or credit cards on the app.

They select a product, continue to Checkout, add their credit card info and they pay.

How can I achieve this?

By the way, this is not a PayPal method.

Here is a screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ann0gkyupzvhe0/payment.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a payment processing API like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) or you can use [Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/) if you don't need access to the payment information.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was searching for!